# How to Professionally Conclude a Collaboration with a Professor to Pursue New Academic Opportunities?

Tags: career-path, academic-life, collaboration, mentoring, professionalism

I've had a fruitful period of collaboration with my current professor, but I'm now looking to explore new academic opportunities and challenges. What is the best approach to professionally conclude my existing working relationship with my professor while maintaining a positive rapport?

I would appreciate advice on navigating this transition, ensuring a respectful and appreciative closure, and potentially seeking guidance for my future endeavors.

Comment: Depending on the academic area, this frequently seems to be easier when one is changing institution than when when is trying to change one's group of collaborators within the same university. Distance frequently disrupts even the best intentions as far as *continuing* collaboration go; when the intention is to loosen one's collaboration ties, the move provides a natural break.

Comment: what do you mean by conclude? You no longer want to work with the current professor even if there are suitable topic? If not, I don't think you need to conclude.